# Using postfix to relay/forward to gmail

Tags: email, debian, postfix, gmail

I have set-up postfix on Debian 6 and I would like to forward emails to my gmail account. This is my /etc/postfix/main.cf file:

```
# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

myhostname = example.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = example.com, localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all

# configure for virtual hosting
virtual_alias_domains = example.com
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
home_mailbox = mail/
```

In my /etc/postfix/virtual file I have:

```
 test@example.com test@gmail.com
```

But when I send an email from hotmail to test@example.com I get the following error:

```
Final-Recipient: rfc822;test@example.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.7.1
Diagnostic-Code: smtp;554 5.7.1 <test@example.com: Relay access denied
```

and /var/log/mail.log says:

```
postfix/smtpd[31752]: connect from mail-qy0-f178.google.com[xxx.xx.xxx.xxx]
postfix/smtpd[31752]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail-qy0-f178.google.com[xxx.xx.xxx.xxx]: 554 5.7.1 <test@example.com>: Relay access denied; from=<example@gmail.com> to=<test@example.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-qy0-f178.google.com>
postfix/smtpd[31752]: disconnect from mail-qy0-f178.google.com[xxx.xx.xxx.xxx]
```

Do I need to be doing something with SMTP authentication?

**Fixed. In the /etc/postfix/main.cf file I had:**

```
mydestination = www.example.com, localhost
```

**replacing with the following got it working:**

```
mydestination = example.com, localhost
```

Comment: I should have been less obtuse in my original question. As my problem was with mydestination param and I just wrote mydestination. In my file I had www.example.com and it should have been example.com

Answer (score 1):

`example.com` is in `mydestination`.
Why don't you add to `/etc/aliases`:

```
test    test@gmail.com
```

Don't forget to run `newaliases` after updating aliases file.

Comment: That is the simplest option, and as long as the rest of the postfix config is working to handle mail sent to your domain it will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see the "virtual_alias_domains" parameter in your /etc/postfix/main.cf file.  Try adding that in:

virtual_alias_domains = example.com

Also, make sure you run the following command:

**postmap /etc/postfix/virtual**

**service postfix reload**

Comment: Tried adding it and reloading but still getting the same error

Comment: Edit your question and show the `virtual_alias_domains`